# As an Access Point (WiFi Repeater): how to set up multiple WiFi/SSID

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, pi-4, systemd-networkd, wpa-supplicant

I had successfully set up my raspberry pi as an access point as WiFi repeater followed this guide: 
[Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with a bridge.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge)

I would like to set up my raspberry pi to broadcast multiple WiFi/SSIDs like how a router can have two or more WiFi to connect to.

I wonder if I could build this with on-chip built-in RPi4 or with additional WiFi dongle(s).

If it’s possible with an only built-in chip of RPi4, how to set it up?

If it’s need additional WiFi-dongle(s), how to set it up?

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't seen a router that can spawn more than 2 access points with different SSIDs. So far as I can see you have to use additional USB/WiFi dongles for additional SSIDs. Maybe there is a way to use different connections on the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz band but I'm just not near by my test environment to have a look at it. Just some moments please.

Comment: If you fingered it out please post it.